# Gradle could not resolve dependency from artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to build an android-library (MyLib1), which depends on another android-library (MyLib2) in gradle and jenkins. I'm a little bit desperated, because I think my gradle files and settings are ok.

I successfully published the first android-library to artifactory. In artifactory, I can see the following dependency declaration:

```
compile(group: 'MyGroup', name: 'MyLib1', version: '1.0', ext: 'aar')
```

I pasted this dependency declaration into my secound build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myvirtualrepository" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.2.0')
  }
}
(...)
dependencies {
  compile (group: 'MyGroup', name: 'MyLib1', version: '1.0', ext: 'aar')
  (...)
}
```

But gradle cannot find the android-library (MyLib1)? I get the following error:

```
 * What went wrong:
 15:50:50.110 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'workspace'.
 15:50:50.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
 15:50:50.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
 15:50:50.112 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not find MyGroup:MyLib1:1.0.
 15:50:50.113 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]         Required by:
 15:50:50.113 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]             MyGroup:workspace:1.0
```

How can I manage to resolve my android-library? Is there a way to "debug" dependencies?

Note: "MyGroup" is a part from "myvirtualrepository"

Edit: trace output from the virtualrepository

```
Request ID: 8c181328
Repo Path ID: myvirtualrepository:mygroup/mylib1/1.0/mylib1-1.0.aar
Method Name: GET
User: admin
Time: 2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00
Thread: http-bio-8081-exec-8
Steps: 
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Received request
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Request source = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Last modified = 01-01-70 00:59:59 CET, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-bio-8081-exec-8
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Retrieving info
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
2013-11-24T18:05:26.079+01:00 Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
2013-11-24T18:05:26.080+01:00 Unable to find resource in myvirtualrepository:mygroup/mylib1/1.0/mylib1-1.0.aar
2013-11-24T18:05:26.080+01:00 Searching for info in aggregated repositories
2013-11-24T18:05:26.080+01:00 Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending the virtual repository 'myvirtualrepository'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending the virtual repository 'myvirtualrepository'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending the virtual repository 'myvirtualrepository'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending collective local repositories
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending collective local cache repositories
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Appending collective remote repositories
2013-11-24T18:05:26.081+01:00 Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.082+01:00 Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.082+01:00 Processing request as a release resource
2013-11-24T18:05:26.082+01:00 Searching for the resource within mylocalrepository
2013-11-24T18:05:26.085+01:00 Resource was found in mylocalrepository
2013-11-24T18:05:26.085+01:00 Resource is an exact match - returning
2013-11-24T18:05:26.085+01:00 Returning resource as found in the aggregated repositories
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Intercepting found resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Intercepting found resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Requested resource is found = true
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Request is HEAD = false
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Responding with found resource
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Found no alternative content handles
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2013-11-24T18:05:26.086+01:00 Creating a resource handle from 'mylocalrepository:mygroup/mylib1/1.0/mylib1-1.0.aar'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.087+01:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2013-11-24T18:05:26.087+01:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '1614343'
2013-11-24T18:05:26.087+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2013-11-24T18:05:26.087+01:00 Responding with selected content handle
2013-11-24T18:05:26.087+01:00 Request succeeded
```

trace command from the localrepository

```
Request ID: f782a19f
Repo Path ID: mylocalrepository:mygroup/mylib1/1.0/mylib1-1.0.aar
Method Name: GET
User: anonymous
Time: 2013-11-25T14:53:09.336+01:00
Thread: http-bio-8081-exec-2
Steps: 
2013-11-25T14:53:09.336+01:00 Received request
2013-11-25T14:53:09.336+01:00 Request source = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Last modified = 01-01-70 00:59:59 CET, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-bio-8081-exec-2
2013-11-25T14:53:09.336+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2013-11-25T14:53:09.336+01:00 Retrieving info
2013-11-25T14:53:09.340+01:00 Requested resource is found = true
2013-11-25T14:53:09.340+01:00 Request is HEAD = false
2013-11-25T14:53:09.340+01:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Responding with found resource
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Found no alternative content handles
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2013-11-25T14:53:09.341+01:00 Creating a resource handle from 'mylocalrepository:mygroup/mylib1/1.0/mylib1-1.0.aar'
2013-11-25T14:53:09.342+01:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2013-11-25T14:53:09.342+01:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '1614343'
2013-11-25T14:53:09.343+01:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2013-11-25T14:53:09.343+01:00 Responding with selected content handle
2013-11-25T14:53:09.343+01:00 Request succeeded
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally worked with the [Gradle Artifactory Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+1.6+Publishing+Artifactory+Plugin), after I removed the Jenkins [Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).

Answer (score 8):

There is an easy way to debug Artifactory resolution - [the trace command](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval).

In your case you should run `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myvirtualrepository/MyGroup/MyLib1/1.0/MyLib1-1.0.jar?trace`

The output is straighforward, but if you need additional help, you can add the output to the question and we'll figure that out.

So, regarding your trace - it shows that the artifact was found and successfully downloaded. Can you download the artifact from the virtual repo using your browser? Browsing to `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myvirtualrepository/MyGroup/MyLib1/1.0/MyLib1-1.0.aar`?

And what about the local repo (`http://localhost:8081/artifactory/mylocalrepository/MyGroup/MyLib1/1.0/MyLib1-1.0.aar`)?

Comment: Thanks for you help, I added the trace command output to my question.

Comment: Yes I can download the library from both, the local- and the virtual repo. I also added the trace output from the local repository.

Comment: So, it's the connectivity of Gradle to Artifactory. Can it be some kind of proxy? Another way to go could be using [Artifactory Gradle plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+1.6+Publishing+Artifactory+Plugin), maybe you'll have more luck with it than with regular Maven resolver.

Comment: There is no proxy, I'm testing artifactory and jenkins on a virtual machine, also  the firewall is turned off. I tried it with the Artifactory Gradle Plugin and got the same error. With --debug option, I noticed this line: 21:26:52.640 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain] Attempting to resolve module 'MyGroup:MyLib1:1.0' using repositories []. The plugin cannot find a list of repositories?

Comment: When I run with ?trace in curl or by launching a browser, it just takes me to the artifactory page that hosts the artifact. Is this trace not supported anymore?