# Artifactory - ?trace finds artifact, gradle does not

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Ughh, the saga continues (my post yesterday - [Gradle could not resolve dependency from artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147980/gradle-could-not-resolve-dependency-from-artifactory)).  I worked out the solution to this (I'm still using hard-coded versions).

But now when I `gradle clean build` the project with a dependency on an artifact in Artifactory gradle fails to find it.  It errors with:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find apirCommon.jar (au.com.apir:apirCommon:1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://devsvr:8090/artifactory/libs-release/au/com/apir/apirCommon/1.0/apirCommon-1.0.jar
```

I can hit this location with a browser or Curl to download the artifact or have a trace on it:

`http://devsrv/artifactory/libs-release/au/com/apir/apirCommon/1.0/apirCommon-1.0.jar?trace`

```
Request ID: 31810f1c
Repo Path ID: libs-release:au/com/apir/apirCommon/1.0/apirCommon-1.0.jar
Method Name: GET
User: admin
Time: 2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00
Thread: http-bio-8090-exec-21
Steps: 
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Received request
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Request source = 203.a.b.c, Last modified = 01-01-70 09:59:59 +10:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-bio-8090-exec-21
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Retrieving info
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Unable to find resource in libs-release:au/com/apir/apirCommon/1.0/apirCommon-1.0.jar
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Searching for info in aggregated repositories
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending collective local repositories
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending collective local cache repositories
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Appending collective remote repositories
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Processing request as a release resource
2015-07-24T11:07:22.236+10:00 Searching for the resource within libs-release-local
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Resource was found in libs-release-local
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Resource is an exact match - returning
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Returning resource as found in the aggregated repositories
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Intercepting found resource with 'PomInterceptor'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Intercepting found resource with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Requested resource is found = true
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Request is HEAD = false
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Request is for a checksum = false
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Responding with found resource
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Executing any AltResponse user plugins that may exist
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Alternative response status is set to -1 and message to 'null'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Found no alternative content handles
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Retrieving a content handle from target repo
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 The requested resource isn't pre-resolved
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Target repository isn't virtual - verifying that downloading is allowed
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Creating a resource handle from 'libs-release-local:au/com/apir/apirCommon/1.0/apirCommon-1.0.jar'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Identified requested resource as a file
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '13368639'
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Responding with selected content handle
2015-07-24T11:07:22.237+10:00 Request succeeded
```

Why can't Gradle download it?  It isn't being downloaded to my local .gradle cache.

[Gradle could not resolve dependency from artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147980/gradle-could-not-resolve-dependency-from-artifactory) has a similar problem though I am using the http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin.

Any thoughts?

---

**Update**

I changed my repo from the virtual `libs-release` to the actual `libs-release-local` and it worked.  I haven't changed the configurations from the default in Artifactory and the virtual `libs-release` includes `libs-release-local` as a selected repository.  Regardless, this virtual repository is resolved when going through curl, browser or ?trace, but not when going through Gradle.  Why?

**And other problem is that then the remote repositories (setup through the virtual `libs-release`) are never used so the build fails as it can't find the remote artifacts**.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by defining a new virtual repository that was exactly the same in every way (except for the name).  Weird.

Further to this, I deleted and recreated a new `libs-release` and the gradle build failed with the same error!  Weirder.